# Drop a jQuery-UI "sortable" item on another element of the page

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a jQuery-UI "sortable" list of items. I want to drop an element from this list elsewhere on the page.

To be specific, it's a CMS. I can reorder content items with jQuery.ui.sortable. I want to drag & drop an element one of those items on the "recycle bin" link, elsewhere on the page.

How can I execute a specific action when I drop a draggable element on a specific element of the page ? How can I get the item on wich I have dropped an item ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar situation, but I've setup a `<div>` for my recycle bin and have made it a connected list.  Here is my script:

```
$('#rubbishBin').sortable({
    placeholder: 'deletingPlaceholder',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.hide();
        // Do what you need to to delete the item from the database
    }
});
$('#itemContainer').sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true,
    delay: 250,
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    placeholder: 'draggingPlaceholder',
    connectWith: '#rubbishBin'
});
```

Comment: Ok, but now you can move the #rubbishBin around, no ?

Comment: Should have pointed out, my #rubbishBin element looks like this: `<div id="rubbishBin">Drag here to delete</div>`. This means that nothing in it can be moved by the user.  The sortable extension will not make a text node draggable.

Comment: It kinda works ; what do you do with the placeholders ? I have trouble figuring out how to use them, it creates a `li` element inside the `rubbisBin` element. Plus, is it normal that the `update` function of the "real" sortable is executed as well ?